# Android. Save and read different values

Tags: android, variables, save, storage

I want to save the value of several variables in the phone's memory, for example, when I press a button a variable is changed and I save it in memory. These variables are in different activities.

On the other hand, I want to open that file and read those variables in another activity. Depending on the value of each variable, I want to display information, images ...

How I can do this? I have tried several examples on this page but I do not get it to work in my application.  Thanks.

Comment: Read the Android Dev Guide on [Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check the android docs for [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). If you don't have too many values to save, then i would recommend to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: I had already tried SharedPreferences but I can not make it work.

I want to store an integer value in an activity and retrieval in another.

What code would have to use with SharedPreferences option in both activities to get it?

Thanks

Comment: Create a new post for that. Show the code that you use and explain exactly what is not working.